# Dropbox' delta api ignores path_prefix

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to call Dropbox' delta Api with a path prefix, however, it seems to ignore it.
Here's my request:

[image: Fiddler Screenshot]

As you can see, I it doesn't care about path_prefix and returns me all files.
Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: I forgot to add the header:

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`